# Eclipse fails to start with errors ("Unhandled event loop exception" etc.) in .metadata/.log

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse could not start. I found the following errors in the workspace directory log file .metadata/.log. I'm using Eclipse 2020-06 on macOS 10.14.6 and Java installed via "brew install openjdk" (for which "java --version" indicates the version is 14). Any idea how to fix it?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2020-07-02 12:38:59.327
!MESSAGE Unable to retrieve the bundle from the URI: bundleclass://org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.ui.fonts/org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.ui.fonts.internal.addon.FontAddon

!ENTRY com.genuitec.eclipse.patches 4 0 2020-07-02 12:38:59.814
!MESSAGE Patches instrumentation extension fix-toolitem (Fixes incorrect toolitem selection on Mac) has failed to weave class org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolItem. Extension will be disabled. Error: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1268)
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1233)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.computeAllFrames(MethodWriter.java:1610)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(MethodWriter.java:1546)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:769)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:649)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.accept(ClassNode.java:465)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.core.AbstractWeaverExtension.weave(AbstractWeaverExtension.java:91)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.patches.internal.InstrumentationManager$WeavingExtension.weave(InstrumentationManager.java:424)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.patches.internal.InstrumentationManager.weave(InstrumentationManager.java:327)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.patches.internal.InstrumentationWeaver.weave(InstrumentationWeaver.java:15)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.weaving.WovenClassImpl.call(WovenClassImpl.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.notifyHookPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:1381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.notifyHooksPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:1358)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.weaving.WovenClassImpl.callHooks(WovenClassImpl.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.weaving.WeavingHookConfigurator.processClass(WeavingHookConfigurator.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.processClass(ClasspathManager.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.MenuAdditionCacheEntry.createToolBarCommandAddition(MenuAdditionCacheEntry.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.MenuAdditionCacheEntry.processToolbarChildren(MenuAdditionCacheEntry.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.MenuAdditionCacheEntry.mergeIntoModel(MenuAdditionCacheEntry.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.MenuPersistence.readAdditions(MenuPersistence.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.MenuPersistence.read(MenuPersistence.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.WorkbenchMenuService.readRegistry(WorkbenchMenuService.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:2305)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4992)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading.runWithoutExceptions(StartupThreading.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.initializeDefaultServices(Workbench.java:2301)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.init(Workbench.java:1640)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2793)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2020-07-02 12:39:00.501
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to 192.168.0.0/16|*.192.168.0.0/16|10.0.0.0/8|*.10.0.0.0/8|172.16.0.0/12|*.172.16.0.0/12|127.0.0.1|localhost|*.localhost|local|*.local by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2020-07-02 12:39:14.535
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.startup.workspace.WorkspaceTracker.lambda$0(WorkspaceTracker.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4124)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3791)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3853)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2020-07-02 12:39:14.554
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.core.util.PlatformUIUtil.getActivePage(PlatformUIUtil.java:68)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.startup.workspace.WorkspaceTracker.lambda$1(WorkspaceTracker.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4124)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3791)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3853)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2020-07-02 12:39:14.809
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.ui.notice.DevStyleNoticeControl.refresh(DevStyleNoticeControl.java:38)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.ui.notice.NoticeService$1.runInUIThread(NoticeService.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob.lambda$0(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4124)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3791)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3853)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.ui 4 0 2020-07-02 12:39:14.864
!MESSAGE Invalid thread access
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1437)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.performStartup(SetupUIPlugin.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.EarlyStartup.earlyStartup(EarlyStartup.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.internal.ui.EarlyStart.run(EarlyStart.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.internal.ui.EarlyStart$1.run(EarlyStart.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2020-07-02 12:39:14.866
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Init AllInOneWorkbenchListener".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Device is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.asyncExec(Display.java:606)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.core.ui.util.AllInOneWorkbenchListener$1.run(AllInOneWorkbenchListener.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2020-07-02 12:39:14.868
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1437)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager$1.done(ProgressManager.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners.doNotify(JobListeners.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners.done(JobListeners.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.endJob(JobManager.java:701)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.endJob(WorkerPool.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:83)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.jreinfo.ui 4 0 2020-07-02 12:39:14.869
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1437)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.refreshPluginActions(AbstractUIPlugin.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin$1.bundleChanged(AbstractUIPlugin.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2020-07-02 12:39:14.870
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Init AllInOneWorkbenchListener".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Device is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.asyncExec(Display.java:606)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.core.ui.util.AllInOneWorkbenchListener$1.run(AllInOneWorkbenchListener.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.p2.ui 4 0 2020-07-02 12:39:14.871
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1437)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.refreshPluginActions(AbstractUIPlugin.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin$1.bundleChanged(AbstractUIPlugin.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui 4 0 2020-07-02 12:39:14.872
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1437)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.refreshPluginActions(AbstractUIPlugin.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin$1.bundleChanged(AbstractUIPlugin.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 4 0 2020-07-02 12:39:14.873
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1437)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.refreshPluginActions(AbstractUIPlugin.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin$1.bundleChanged(AbstractUIPlugin.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.editors 4 0 2020-07-02 12:39:14.874
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1437)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.refreshPluginActions(AbstractUIPlugin.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin$1.bundleChanged(AbstractUIPlugin.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor 4 0 2020-07-02 12:39:14.875
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1437)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.refreshPluginActions(AbstractUIPlugin.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin$1.bundleChanged(AbstractUIPlugin.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 0 2020-07-02 12:39:14.875
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1437)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.refreshPluginActions(AbstractUIPlugin.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin$1.bundleChanged(AbstractUIPlugin.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY com.genuitec.eclipse.inlinesearch 4 0 2020-07-02 12:39:14.876
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1437)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.refreshPluginActions(AbstractUIPlugin.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin$1.bundleChanged(AbstractUIPlugin.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2020-07-02 12:39:14.935
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager.getUniqueDescriptors(AbstractWorkingSetManager.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager.bundleChanged(AbstractWorkingSetManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

And my eclipse.ini looks like

```
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.1200.v20200508-1552
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
#-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-Xmn512m
-Xss2m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
```

Comment: Looks like whatever plugins you have from Genuitec are causing it to crash. You should contact them for support.

Comment: Clearly, the Genuitec plug-ins (Darkest Dark Theme / DevStyle, etc.?) cause a couple of issues and slow down the startup (they do runtime weaving to cheat Eclipse being open source), but it might also in the `eclipse.ini` the line `#-XX:+UseG1GC` that prevents Eclipse from starting. What error message do you get exactly when you try to start Eclipse (if the error message refers to the log file, it is not `#-XX:+UseG1GC`)?

Comment: Is there a way to turn off or uninstall the Genuitec plug-ins (Darkest Dark Theme / DevStyle, etc.?) without being able to properly start Eclipse?

Comment: That depends. If starting fails after something is written into the log, probably yes. That's why I asked you what error message do you get exactly when you try to start Eclipse.